# Requests login into website only getting 403 error

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to login into www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de using the requests library, but every time I try to post my data (on the register page its the same as on the login page) I am getting a 403 error.

Here is the code for the register function:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'user-agent': user_agent, 'Referer': 'https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de'}

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-benutzer-anmeldung.html'
    c.headers = headers
    hp = c.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(hp.content, 'html.parser')
    crsf = soup.find('input', {'name': '_csrf'})['value']
    print(crsf)

    payload = dict(email='test.email@emailzz1.de', password='test123', passwordConfirmation='test123',
                   _marketingOptIn='on', _crsf=crsf)

    page = c.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(page.text)
    print(page.url)
    print(page.status_code)
```

Is the problem that I need some more headers? Isn't a user-agent and a referrer enough?

I have tried adding all requested headers, but then I am getting no response.

Comment: I dont know if this is helpful but a similar thing happened to me a while ago, and I found that I couldn't overcome the problem-some sites are really set. against.bot.=s accessing them. I hope you will find a solution.

Comment: @3141 Yes, ch4rl1e97 provided me a good solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to create a script that will successfully complete the register form you're trying to fill in using the [`mechanicalsoup` library](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). Note you will have to *manually* check your email account for the email they send you to complete registration.

I realise this doesn't actually answer the question of why BeautifulSoup returned a 403 forbidden error however it does complete your task without encountering the same error.

```py
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

browser.open("https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-benutzer-anmeldung.html")

browser.select_form('#registration-form')
browser.get_current_form().print_summary()
browser["email"] = "mailuser@emailprovider.com"
browser["password"] = "testSO12345"
browser["passwordConfirmation"] = "testSO12345"

response = browser.submit_selected()
rsp_code = response.status_code

#print(response.text)
print("Response code:",rsp_code)
if(rsp_code == 200):
    print("Success! Opening a local debug copy of the page... (no CSS formatting)")
    browser.launch_browser()
else:
    print("Failure!")
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, i also tryed it with mechanicalsoup, but i found nothing about a hashtag which have to be before the form-name. So well, thank you!

Comment: There is just one more thing, i am trying now to upload a img on ebay-kleinanzeigen.de by a post message, which is no problem for me, but where can i see the url of the uploaded img? In my chrome network manager is after the upload a get request with the url, but how i get this with the mechanize browser? Is there any way to get this automaticlly send get requests?

Comment: Its the same principe like on this page, i upload the image and a automatic GET requet appears
https://imgur.com/upload

Comment: @OliverW regarding the "hashtag", it indicates you're looking for something by its "id", the same way that CSS selectors work. Have a look at the MechaSoup getting started guide for more examples.

For everything else you mention, perhaps that's worthy of its own question, as I'm not sure on that myself. Again have a look through the documentation, perhaps you'll find it there?

Comment: Oh okay, now i read more trough the mechanicalsoup documentation and i really love it. The function .launch_browser() is really great! About the image upload, maybe you could help me. Now i am trying to upload a img for testing to this website: https://pasteboard.co/, with this post message: payload = {"file": open('C:\\Users\\Oli\\Downloads\\Ins\\1.jpg', 'rb')}
response = browser.post('https://pasteboard.co/upload', payload), but i am getting a 500 response because of no existing file, but the file is existing. Do you maybe know what to do?